# Medir la replicación en un cluster PostgreSQL desde Grafana

Tags: postgresql, grafana

Estoy buscando la manera correcta de monitorear en grafana la replica entre un cluster PostgreSQL.

En la version que estoy trabajando están disponibles las siguientes metricas:

pg_stat_replication_reply_time, pg_stat_replication_pg_wal_lsn_diff & pg_stat_replication_pg_current_wal_lsn_bytes

Actualmente estoy trabajando con la metrica pg_stat_replication_reply_time [**rate(pg_stat_replication_reply_time{state="streaming"}[5m])**] que según lo investigado mide el tiempo que tarda la escritura desde el nodo primario a los standby.

Es la primera ocasión que trabajo con estas herramientas de monitoreo, me pueden asesorar acerca de si la métrica que estoy utilizando es la correcta, por favor?